# axios.get not passing params from client side to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

As the title, axios.get not passing params from client side to the server.
My server is currently on localhost:3001, and my client side is on http://127.0.0.1:5555. Client side is not React, so it's currently on http://127.0.0.1:5555/WeatherApp/index.html (I opened the index.html file, the "entry point of the app," on chrome from vscode by using FiveServer, and it is the port the client is being hosted)

Client side code:

```
export async function fetchData() {
  const { data } = 
  await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api', {
    params: {q: 'Paris'}
  })
  return data
}
```

Server side code:

```
app.get("/api", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query)
  const response = await axios.get('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json', {
    params: {
      key: process.env.KEY,
      q: 'Paris'
    }
  })
  const { data } = response
  res.send(data)
})
```

The console.log(req.query) in server code printed an empty object. I also tried req.params, but it also printed an empty object (while i want to see "Paris"). Tried console.log(req) to see where the word "Paris" might be nested, but nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a body with your request, you'd be looking to make a POST request, as GET as you dont pass a body with it, but you can use parameters in your URL to pass information to the sever in a GET request

You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Comment: yup the second is what I want to do here: use GET request and use parameters in the URL to pass info to server.

Comment: I should also add that although i can't see the params i pass to the server on the console, when I use 'req.query.myparams' in my server to fetch data from an external API, it actually does work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these two code snippets and it actually works... Maybe you're missing something essential:

server.js

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query)
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

client.js

```js
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api', {
      params: {q: 'Paris'}    
}).then(({data}) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should add that although i can't see the params i pass from the client to the server on the console, when I use 'req.query.myparams' in my server to fetch data from an external API, it actually does work... So the problem really is that, I can't see anything printed on my console (just an empty object)

Comment: is it your client's console log you can't see anything? or your servers? Cedric's code snippets above are working, the `console.log(req.query)` in the GET route returns `{ q: 'Paris' }`

Comment: @JacobStephenson It's the server console that's not showing (the req.query not showing { q: 'Paris' }

Comment: Maybe you should inspect what is sent to the server in the e.g. chrome dev tools (`Network` tab). And maybe check if there is actually a request...